# Author's Icollection of associated names count = 0

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core

**A Asp.net.core project for webbApplication Razorpage**

I am currently working on an Asp.net.core project for a web application that uses Razorpages. I am encountering a problem with binding the frontend and backend using JavaScript for my "Author" model, which has a many-to-many relationship with associated names and official websites. Whenever I press

> Add New Author

, the JavaScript code generates multiple HTML elements for the authors, in this case, three authors, which are then displayed on the front-end. However, when looping through the back-end, the "Count" for "Author" is displayed correctly (i.e., 3), but the counts for "Official Websites" and "Associated Names" are always 0, regardless of the input.

Since each "Author" can have multiple "Official Websites" and "Associated Names", there should be at least two counts for each when looping through the back-end. I don't think I need to include "Associated Names" and "Official Websites" since I am creating a new author, but I am unsure how to fix the front-end so that the associated names and official websites for each author are correctly bound to the back-end.

**To clarify,** I removed "Official Websites" from the HTML and back-end example, as it follows the same problem as "Associated Names".

Edit* I attempted to solve the issue by removing the two hidden fields for "Associated Names" and "Official Websites". However, after doing so, the back-end returned null instead of count 0. T

```
 public class AuthorModel
{
    [Key]
    public int AuthorID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<OfficalWebsite>? OfficalWebsites { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AssociatedNames>? AssociatedNames { get; set; }

}
 Author here gives Count correctly So if i had 3, i get COUNT 3. 
 foreach (var author in Author)
        {
            
            var newAuthor = new AuthorModel
            {
                FirstName = author.FirstName,
              
                AssociatedNames = new List<AssociatedNames>(),
                OfficalWebsites = new List<OfficalWebsite>()
            };

          
            await context.authorModels.AddAsync(newAuthor);
            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            COUNT Will always be 0 Here. 
            if (author.AssociatedNames != null)
            {
                foreach (var associatedName in author.AssociatedNames)
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(associatedName.nameString))
                    {
                        var newAssociatedName = new AssociatedNames
                        {
                            nameString = associatedName.nameString,
                          
                            AuthorModel = newAuthor
                        };
                        await associatedNamesRepsitory.AddAsync(newAssociatedName);
                        newAuthor.AssociatedNames.Add(newAssociatedName);
                    }
                }
            }
         }
```

All of the Front end

```
  <button id="addRow" type="button" asp-for="Author" class="btn btn-info">Add New Author</button>
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="MangaID" value="@Model.MangaID" />
<div id="newRow">
    <input type="hidden" id="total" value="0" />
</div>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Post" />
```

The JavaScript

```
 $("#addRow").click(function () {
var rowCount = parseInt($("#total").val());
console.log("Add button clicked");
rowCount++;
$("#total").val(rowCount);
var html = '';
html += '<div id="inputRow">';

html += '<label for="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__FirstName">Author ' + rowCount + ' First Name</label>';
html += '<input type="text" id="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__FirstName" name="Author[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].FirstName" class="form-control" required />';
html += '<input type="hidden" id="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__OfficalWebsites" name="Author[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].OfficalWebsites" class="form-control" />';
html += '<input type="hidden" id="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__AssociatedNames" name="Author[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].AssociatedNames" class="form-control" multiple />';
html += '<button id="removeRow" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Remove</button>';

html += '</div>';

THIS Is where i believe i'm doing something wrong
html += '<div class="associated-names-container">';
html += '<h3>Associated Names</h3>';
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    html += '<label for="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__AssociatedNames_' + i + '_nameString">Associated Name ' + (i + 1) + '</label>';
    html += '<input type="text" id="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__AssociatedNames_' + i + '_nameString" name="Author.AssociatedNames[' + i + '].nameString" class="form-control" />';
}
html += '</div>';




     $('#newRow').append(html);
          });
    $(document).on('click', '#removeRow', function () {
    var rowCount = parseInt($("#total").val());
   rowCount--;
    $("#total").val(rowCount);
     $(this).closest('#inputRow').remove();
      });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not binding to the corresponding property, so there is no data in `author.AssociatedNames`.

According to your code, the parameter Author received in the `OnPost` method should be of `List` type, so `Author.AssociatedNames[' + i + '].nameString` cannot match the corresponding attribute.

After removing the two hidden fields for `Associated Names` and `Official Websites`, you need to change `Author.AssociatedNames[' + i + '].nameString` to `Author[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].AssociatedNames[' + i + '].nameString`:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    html += '<label for="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__AssociatedNames_' + i + '_nameString">Associated Name ' + (i + 1) + '</label>';
    html += '<input type="text" id="Author_' + (rowCount - 1) + '__AssociatedNames_' + i + '_nameString" name="Author[' + (rowCount - 1) + '].AssociatedNames[' + i + '].nameString" class="form-control" />';
}
```

Test Result:
[image]

Comment: That is correct, I didn't use the List<AuthorModel> on the Post. Thanks for the help Chen!